# Android 4.1.2 platform messing with background color

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing very weird issue with 4.1.2 platform. My `LinearLayout` has following background set in xml:

```
 android:background="@android:color/white"
```

I am using `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layout.

On **Samsung S3** the result is nothing but white, seems to be closer to gray.

I am using `minSdk 10` and `targetSdk 20`, building the project using sdk 18.

Anyone else encountered the same or similar issue and got some insight how to fix/workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a custom theme on the device?

Comment: The device is using its default theme.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is to call `setBackgroundColor` in java code. Not pretty, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Use white colour hex code `#ffffff` instead of referencing(`"@android:color/white"`).

Hope it may helpful to you.

Thanks,

Bhuvnesh